# Pythonic way to combine (interleave, interlace, intertwine) two lists in an alternating fashion?

Tags: python

I have two lists, **the first of which is guaranteed to contain exactly one more item than the second**. I would like to know the most Pythonic way to create a new list whose even-index values come from the first list and whose odd-index values come from the second list.

```
# example inputs
list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o']
list2 = ['hello', 'world']

# desired output
['f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o']
```

This works, but isn't pretty:

```
list3 = []
while True:
    try:
        list3.append(list1.pop(0))
        list3.append(list2.pop(0))
    except IndexError:
        break
```

How else can this be achieved? What's the most Pythonic approach?

---

<sub>If you need to handle lists of *mismatched length* (e.g. the second list is longer, or the first has more than one element more than the second), some solutions here will work while others will require adjustment. For more specific answers, see [How to interleave two lists of different length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199961/) to leave the excess elements at the end, or [How to elegantly interleave two lists of uneven length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293481/) to try to intersperse elements evenly, or [Insert element in Python list after every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040525) for the case where a specific number of elements should come before each "added" element.</sub>

Comment: @Paul: Yes, the accepted answer does not give the complete solution. Read the comments and the other answers. The question is basically the same and the other solutions can be applied here.

Comment: @Felix: I respectfully disagree. It is true, the questions are in the same neighborhood but not really duplicates. As vague proof take a look at the potential answers here and compare with the other question.

Comment: Check out these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529376/pythonic-way-to-mix-two-lists

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Here's one way to do it by slicing:

```
>>> list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> list2 = ['hello', 'world']
>>> result = [None]*(len(list1)+len(list2))
>>> result[::2] = list1
>>> result[1::2] = list2
>>> result
['f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o']
```

Comment: Thanks, Duncan. I did not realize that it's possible to specify a step when slicing. What I like about this approach is how naturally it reads.

1. Make a list of the correct length.
2. Populated the even indexes with the contents of list1.
3. Populate the odd indexes with the contents of list2.

The fact that the lists are of different lengths is not an issue in this case!

Comment: I think it only works when len(list1) - len(list2) is 0 or 1.

Comment: If the lists are of appropriate lengths then it works, if not then the original question doesn't specify what answer is expected. It can be easily modified to handle most reasonable situations: for example if you wanted extra elements to be ignored just chop down the longer list before you start; if you want the extra elements interleaved with None then just make sure that result is initialised with some more None's; if you want extra elements just added on the end then do as for ignoring them and then append them.

Comment: Quite right, Duncan; I like your solution. My previous comment was really directed at davidchambers in stating that lengths weren't an issue. Sorry for not being explicit.

Comment: I, too, was unclear. The point I was trying to make is that Duncan's solution, unlike many of those listed, is not complicated by the fact that the lists are of unequal length. Sure, it's applicable in only a limited range of situations, but I'd prefer a really elegant solution that works in this instance to a less elegant solution that works for any two lists.

Comment: You can use (2*len(list1)-1) instead of (len(list1)+len(list2)), also i prefer [0::2] instead of [::2].

Comment: +1 works like proposed, but fails if list2 = ['hello'] ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 3 to extended slice of size 2

Comment: That should never occur in this particular case, killown. I'm using re.split() which, when used with a capturing group, always returns a list containing an odd number of items. I'm then processing the "evens" and "odds" separately before combining them into a single list using Duncan's technique. http://bitbucket.org/davidchambers/mango/changeset/6ec62ff16207

Comment: This isn't a very pythonic solution: creating the lists in advance can be very wasteful for large inputs, and I think using the total length of the input iters is also unpythonic. There's much cleaner solutions below which produce lazy generators (which can of course easily be coerced to a list as desired).

Comment: @Dubslow are you the ultimate arbiter of Pythonic? The question asked about combining two lists which is exactly what this answer gives you. The other answers involving iterators already existed when I wrote my answer and I don't believe in duplicating existing answers so I merely set about filling in the gap they had left. For a question such as this there are many good (and Pythonic) answers and no one answer is best in all cases.

Answer (score 56):

There's a recipe for this in the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (note: for Python 3):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Comment: I find this way more complicated than it needs to be. There's a better option below using `zip_longest`.

Comment: @Dubslow For this particular case, yeah, this is probably overkill (as I mentioned in a comment elsewhere), unless you happen to already have access to it. It might have some advantages in other situations though. This recipe certainly wasn't designed for this problem, it just happens to solve it.

Comment: fyi you should use the recipe in the `itertools` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) because `.next()` no longer works.

Comment: @johnw. one has to use `__next__`. It isn't written in the documentation so I proposed an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Marine I would kind of rather you had just changed the existing code sample, but I can fix that myself. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: python version greater than 3 made me laugh... I am always eager to get a peep at what python 4 code would look like.

Answer (score 55):

```
import itertools

print(
    [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2)) if x]
)
```

I think this is the most pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Why this isn't the accepted answer? This is the shortest and most pythonic and works with different list lengths!

Comment: the method name is zip_longest not izip_longest

Comment: The problem with this is that the default fillin value from zip_longest might overwrite `None`s that are *supposed to be in the list. I'll edit in a tweaked version to fix this

Comment: Note: This will cause problems if the lists contain elements with value `False`, or even things that will only be _evaluated_ as `False` by the `if`-expression, like for example a `0` or an empty list. This can be (partially) avoided by the following: `[x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2)) if x is not None]`. Of course, this will still not work if the lists contain `None` elements that need to be preserved. In this case, you need to change the `fillvalue` argument of `zip_longest`, as Dubslow already suggested.

Comment: `None` problem seems to be gone, at least since Python 3.7.6 (I don't know for older versions).  If `alt_chain` is defined as `def alt_chain(*iters, fillvalue=None): return chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*iters, fillvalue=fillvalue))`, then `list(alt_chain([0, False, 1, set(), 3, 4], [0, None, 1, {}], fillvalue=99))` correctly returns `[0, 0, False, None, 1, 1, set(), {}, 3, 99, 4, 99]`.

Comment: @paime: The problem doesn't occur in your code because you didn't filter the results (no `if x` at the end of a listcomp). You end up with a different problem, inserting a bunch of `99`s into the data that don't exist in either input.

Comment: @paime:  It's possible to modify the OP's code to work properly by using a custom sentinel instead of a simple boolean check though: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDLTsMwEEX3/YorsWhTWQgoK6SukNjBD1RVNUkm6YAzdm0HtSC@PdhVoV75cT3n6PpT2jtdTV1wAyRxSM7ZCBm8CwnLqeUOZNOu2ZPoYlkSsXqaIa/ImkTZYg1Xv3OTFhVwg1f6YBD6kQJpYm4xqhxGvoTOXwOnMSg2R3Qu4AhRnAG3RWNXIFRbXnyJ31mnPcd0QRt0Yu0n2ZHXf/yqgnRlSIS69K@1LTLPbvAUGMlddesTpC2HdDrjo8@SBqQtooOnXIh1vTRkL8oRDek8obEkQxlVM/gw5ve8J80NivYzH0Sz5rWszZ3BC9nIBg8m43M/BiuDx63B5t7gzSmfL75/tlUJ@PXcYF5N0y8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 33):

In Python 2, this should do what you want:

```
>>> iters = [iter(list1), iter(list2)]
>>> print list(it.next() for it in itertools.cycle(iters))
['f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o']
```

Comment: I really liked your initial answer. Though it did not perfectly address the question, it was an elegant way to merge two lists of the same length. I suggest retaining it, along with the lenght caveat, in your current answer.

Comment: This is similar to David's answer, but is strictly interleaving (it will stop rather than continue with later lists)

Comment: @cobbal: Isn't that what he wanted?

Comment: This will only work when the lengths of the lists are with 1 of each other.  No down vote though as this partial solution is really elegant.

Comment: @caspin: *This will only work when the lengths of the lists are with 1 of each other.* What do you mean? It seems to work fine for any lengths. Can you give an example of where it gives a different result from the OPs code?

Comment: If list1 were instead ['f', 'o', 'o', 'd'], its final item ('d') would not appear in the resulting list (which is totally fine given the specifics of the question). This is an elegant solution!

Comment: @Mark yep (I did upvote it), just pointing out the differences (and limitations if other people want different behavior)

Comment: +1 for solving the stated problem, and for doing it simply too :-) I figured something like this would be possible. Honestly I think the `roundrobin` function is sort of overkill for this situation.

Comment: >>> def rr(*iterables):
...   return (i.next() for i in itertools.cycle(map(iter, iterables)))

Comment: This is a great option, but I've chosen Duncan's approach because of its self-descriptive nature.

Comment: To work with lists of any size you can simply append what's left in the iterators to the result: `list(itertools.chain(map(next, itertools.cycle(iters)), *iters))`

Comment: This does not work in Python 3.6 `import itertools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o']
    list2 = ['hello', 'world']
    iters = [iter(list1), iter(list2)]
    print( list(it.next() for it in itertools.cycle(iters)) )` giving:
`AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 24):

If both lists have equal length, you can do:

```
[x for y in zip(list1, list2) for x in y]
```

As the first list has one more element, you can add it post hoc:

```
[x for y in zip(list1, list2) for x in y] + [list1[-1]]
```

Edit: To illustrate what is happening in that first list comprehension, this is how you would spell it out as a nested for loop:

```
result = []
for y in zip(list1, list2): # y is is a 2-tuple, containining one element from each list
    for x in y: # iterate over the 2-tuple
        result.append(x) # append each element individually
```

Comment: ^This should be the answer, python has become more pythonic in the last 10 years

Comment: Very pythonic but it hurts my small brain. How should I parse this?

Answer (score 21):

Without itertools and assuming l1 is 1 item longer than l2:

```
>>> sum(zip(l1, l2+[0]), ())[:-1]
('f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o')
```

In python 2, using itertools and assuming that lists don't contain None:

```
>>> filter(None, sum(itertools.izip_longest(l1, l2), ()))
('f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o')
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer. It's so concise.

Comment: @anishtain4 zip takes pairs of elements as tuples from lists, `[(l1[0], l2[0]), (l1[1], l2[1]), ...]`. `sum` concatenates tuples together: `(l1[0], l2[0]) + (l1[1], l2[1]) + ...` resulting in interleaved lists. Rest of the one-line is just padding of l1 with extra element for zip to work and slice till -1 to get rid of that padding.

Comment: izip_longest (zip_longest since python 3) doesn't need +[0] padding, it implicitly fills None when lengths of lists don't match, while `filter(None, ...` (could use `bool` instead, or `None.__ne__`) removes false values, including 0, None and empty strings, so second expression isn't strictly equivalent to first one.

Comment: The question is how did you make `sum` do that? What is the role of the second argument there? In the documentations, the second argument is `start`.

Comment: Default value of start is 0, and you can't do 0+(some, tuple), thus start is changed to empty tuple.

Comment: Without padding and its removal: `sum(zip(l2, l1[1:]), (l1[0],))`.

Answer (score 15):

I know the questions asks about two lists with one having one item more than the other, but I figured I would put this for others who may find this question.

Here is [Duncan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion#3678938) adapted to work with two lists of different sizes.

```
list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
list2 = ['hello', 'world']
num = min(len(list1), len(list2))
result = [None]*(num*2)
result[::2] = list1[:num]
result[1::2] = list2[:num]
result.extend(list1[num:])
result.extend(list2[num:])
result
```

This outputs:

```
['f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a one liner that does it:

`list3 = [ item for pair in zip(list1, list2 + [0]) for item in pair][:-1]`

Comment: This works correctly but strikes me as inelegant since it's doing so much to achieve something so simple. I'm not saying that this approach is inefficient, simply that it's not particularly easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner using list comprehensions, w/o other libraries:

```
list3 = [sub[i] for i in range(len(list2)) for sub in [list1, list2]] + [list1[-1]]
```

Here is another approach, if you allow alteration of your initial list1 by side effect:

```
[list1.insert((i+1)*2-1, list2[i]) for i in range(len(list2))]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is based on Carlos Valiente's contribution above 
with an option to alternate groups of multiple items and make sure that all items are present in the output :

```
A=["a","b","c","d"]
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

def cyclemix(xs, ys, n=1):
    for p in range(0,int((len(ys)+len(xs))/n)):
        for g in range(0,min(len(ys),n)):
            yield ys[0]
            ys.append(ys.pop(0))
        for g in range(0,min(len(xs),n)):
            yield xs[0]
            xs.append(xs.pop(0))

print [x for x in cyclemix(A, B, 3)]
```

This will interlace lists A and B by groups of 3 values each:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 'd', 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd', 'a', 7, 8, 9, 'b', 'c', 'd', 10, 11, 12, 'a', 'b', 'c', 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late buy yet another python one-liner. This works when the two lists have equal or unequal size. One thing worth nothing is it will modify a and b. If it's an issue, you need to use other solutions.

```
a = ['f', 'o', 'o']
b = ['hello', 'world']
sum([[a.pop(0), b.pop(0)] for i in range(min(len(a), len(b)))],[])+a+b
['f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*zip('abc', 'def')))  # Note: this only works for lists of equal length
['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']
```

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) returns an iterator of tuple pairs with any missing elements in one list replaced with `fillvalue=None` (passing `fillvalue=object` lets you use `None` as a value). If you [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/6243352) these pairs, then filter `fillvalue` in a list comprehension, this gives:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> def merge(a, b):
...     return [
...         x for y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=object)
...         for x in y if x is not object
...     ]
...
>>> merge("abc", "defgh")
['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> merge([0, 1, 2], [4])
[0, 4, 1, 2]
>>> merge([0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
[0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8]
```

Generalized to arbitrary iterables:

```py
>>> def merge(*its):
...     return [
...         x for y in zip_longest(*its, fillvalue=object)
...         for x in y if x is not object
...     ]
...
>>> merge("abc", "lmn1234", "xyz9", [None])
['a', 'l', 'x', None, 'b', 'm', 'y', 'c', 'n', 'z', '1', '9', '2', '3', '4']
>>> merge(*["abc", "x"]) # unpack an iterable
['a', 'x', 'b', 'c']
```

Finally, you may want to return a generator rather than a list comprehension:

```py
>>> def merge(*its):
...     return (
...         x for y in zip_longest(*its, fillvalue=object)
...         for x in y if x is not object
...     )
...
>>> merge([1], [], [2, 3, 4])
<generator object merge.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001996B466740>
>>> next(merge([1], [], [2, 3, 4]))
1
>>> list(merge([1], [], [2, 3, 4]))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you're OK with other packages, you can try [`more_itertools.roundrobin`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin):

```py
>>> list(roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF'))
['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
a = "hlowrd"
b = "el ol"

def func(xs, ys):
    ys = iter(ys)
    for x in xs:
        yield x
        yield ys.next()

print [x for x in func(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def combine(list1, list2):
    lst = []
    len1 = len(list1)
    len2 = len(list2)

    for index in range( max(len1, len2) ):
        if index+1 <= len1:
            lst += [list1[index]]

        if index+1 <= len2:
            lst += [list2[index]]

    return lst
```

Comment: Be very careful when using mutable default arguments. This will only return the correct answer the first time it's called, as lst will be reused for every call thereafter. This would be better written as lst=None ... if lst is None: lst = [], although I don't see a compelling reason to opt for this approach over others listed here.

Comment: lst is defined within the function so is a local variable. The potential problem is that list1 and list2 are will be reused every time you use the function, even if you call the function with different lists. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: @blokeley: wrong, would be reused if it was combine(list1=[...], list2=[...])

Comment: When this solution was first posted its first line read `def combine(list1, list2, lst=[]):`, hence my comment. By the time I submitted that comment, though, killown had made the necessary change.

Answer (score 1):

How about numpy? It works with strings as well:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([[a,b] for a,b in zip([1,2,3],[2,3,4,5,6])]).ravel()
```

Result:

```
array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Stops on the shortest:

```
def interlace(*iters, next = next) -> collections.Iterable:
    """
    interlace(i1, i2, ..., in) -> (
        i1-0, i2-0, ..., in-0,
        i1-1, i2-1, ..., in-1,
        .
        .
        .
        i1-n, i2-n, ..., in-n,
    )
    """
    return map(next, cycle([iter(x) for x in iters]))
```

Sure, resolving the next/__next__ method may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple one-liners inspired by [answers to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529376/pythonic-way-to-mix-two-lists):

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=object)))[:-1]

[i for l in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=object) for i in l if i is not object]

[item for sublist in map(None, list1, list2) for item in sublist][:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in a functional & immutable way (Python 3):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda lst, zipped: [*lst, *zipped] if zipped[1] != None else [*lst, zipped[0]], zip_longest(list1, list2),[])
```

Answer (score 0):

using for loop also we can achive this easily:

```
list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o']
list2 = ['hello', 'world']
list3 = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    #print(list3)
    list3.append(list1[i])
    if i < len(list2):
        list3.append(list2[i])
        
print(list3)
```

output :

```
['f', 'hello', 'o', 'world', 'o']
```

Further by using **list comprehension** this can be reduced. But for understanding this loop can be used.

Comment: This one is easier: for i in range(len(list2)): list3.append(list1[i]) list3.append(list2[i])
     #after the loop
list3.append(list1[i])        
print(list3)

Comment: You can edit your answer if you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My approach looks as follows:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

def intersperse(*iterators):
    # A random object not occurring in the iterators
    filler = object()

    r = (x for x in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*iterators, fillvalue=filler)) if x is not filler)

    return r

list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o']
list2 = ['hello', 'world']

print(list(intersperse(list1, list2)))
```

It works for an arbitrary number of iterators and yields an iterator, so I applied `list()` in the print line.

Answer (score 0):

```
def alternate_elements(small_list, big_list):
mew = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(small_list)):
    mew.append(small_list[i])
    mew.append(big_list[i])
    count +=1
return mew+big_list[count:]

if len(l2)>len(l1):
    res = alternate_elements(l1,l2)
else:
    res = alternate_elements(l2,l1)

print(res)
```

Here we swap lists based on size and perform, can someone provide better solution with time complexity O(len(l1)+len(l2))

Answer (score -1):

I'd do the simple:

```
chain.from_iterable( izip( list1, list2 ) )
```

It'll come up with an iterator without creating any additional storage needs.

Comment: It's really simple, but it only works with lists of the same length!

Comment: You can fix it with `chain.from_iterable(izip(list1, list2), list1[len(list2):])` for the particular problem asked here ... list1 is supposed to be the longer one.

Comment: Yeah but I'd rather come up with either a solution that works for arbitrary length containers or yield to the solutions proposed above.

Answer (score -1):

This is nasty but works no matter the size of the lists:

```
list3 = [
    element for element in 
    list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([
        val for val in itertools.izip_longest(list1, list2)
    ]))
    if element != None
]
```

Comment: `list()` is unnecessary and time/space inefficient. There are [easier ways to do this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69057908/6243352).

Answer (score -1):

Obviously late to the party, but here's a concise one for equal-length lists:

```
output = [e for sub in zip(list1,list2) for e in sub]
```

It generalizes for an arbitrary number of equal-length lists, too:

```
output = [e for sub in zip(list1,list2,list3) for e in sub]
```

etc.

Comment: This doesn't solve the original question which is about lists of different length.

Answer (score -2):

I'm too old to be down with list comprehensions, so:

```
import operator
list3 = reduce(operator.add, zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily quadratic.

Comment: I don't see where it is quadratic, but this is another solution working only for lists of same length, so it doesn't solve the original question.