# Pythonic way to mix two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists of length n and n+1:

```
[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]
[b_1, b_2, ..., b_(n+1)]
```

I want a function giving as a result a list with alternate elements from the two, that is

```
[b_1, a_1, ..., b_n, a_n, b_(n+1)]
```

The following works, but does not look smart:

```
def list_mixing(list_long,list_short):
    list_res = []
    for i in range(len(list_short)):
        list_res.extend([list_long[i], list_short[i]])
    list_res.append(list_long[-1])
    return list_res
```

Can anyone suggest a more pythonic way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMHO the best way is:

```
result = [item for sublist in zip(a,b) for item in sublist]
```

It's also faster than sum and reduce ways.

**UPD** Sorry missed that your second list is bigger by one element :)
There is another crazy way:

```
result = [item for sublist in map(None, a, b) for item in sublist][:-1]
```

Comment: but it is very pythonic. that's clean and short and readable. my preferred solution so far.

Comment: I like it as well, it doesn't solve the problem completely, but there is no other solution that solves it in one passage. I will have to append the last element afterwards!

Comment: Second solution is not so elegant, but solves your problem :)

Answer (score 18):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> b
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b)))
['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e', '6', 'f']
```

`zip()` produces a iterable with the length of shortest argument. You can either append `a[-1]` to the result, or use `itertools.zip_longest`(izip_longest for Python 2.x) with a fill value and delete that value afterwards.

And you can use more than two input sequences with this solution.

For not appending the last value, you can try this dirty approach, but I don't really recommend it, it isn't clear:

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> [a[i//2] if i%2 else b[i//2] for i in range(len(a)*2+1)]
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4, 'e', 5, 'f']
```

(For Python 2.x, use single `/`)

Comment: This is nice, I am a bit annoyed by the appending of the last element but I guess there is not much one could do about it

Comment: First bit of code does not answer the question, second bit is overly complicated.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> long = [1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> short = [2, 4, 6]
>>> mixed = []
>>> for i in range(len(long)):
>>>     mixed.append(long[i])
>>>     if i < len(short)
>>>         mixed.append(short[i])
>>> mixed
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Compared to the other answers, mine doesn't seem pythonic enough.

Comment: 'Pythonic' does not mean complicated one-liners -- yours is a good, readable solution.  That's Pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

[more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) has [roundrobin](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin) which exactly does the job:

```
from more_itertools import roundrobin

l1 = [1, 3, 5]
l2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

print(list(roundrobin(l1,l2)))
# [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

mixing two lists is a job for `zip`:

```
res = []
for a,b in zip(list_long, list_short):
    res += [a,b]
```

for lists of differing lengths, define your own function:

```
def mix(list_long, list_short):
    result = []
    i,j = iter(list_long), iter(list_short)
    for a,b in zip(i,j):
        res += [a,b]
    for rest in i:
        result += rest
    for rest in j:
        result += rest
    return result
```

using the [answer given by Mihail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529376/pythonic-way-to-mix-two-lists/7529533#7529533), we can shorten this to:

```
def mix(list_long, list_short):
    i,j = iter(list_long), iter(list_short)
    result = [item for sublist in zip(i,j) for item in sublist]
    result += [item for item in i]
    result += [item for item in j]
    return result
```

Comment: The resulting list will be truncated in length so you'll miss the remaining elements in the longer list.

Comment: Good approach, but be careful: This works only, if both lists have the same length (zip truncates the longer of both lists).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a combination of the above answers:

```
>>> a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

>>> [i for l in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=object) for i in l if i is not object]
<<< ['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e', '6', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Great answer. Use `zip_longest` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use `izip_longest` filling the gaps with something you don't have in your lists, or don't want to keep in the result. If you don't want to keep anything resolving to `False`, use the defaults for `izip_longest` and `filter`:

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest
l1 = [1,3,5]
l2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
filter(None, chain(*izip_longest(l1,l2)))
```

the result is: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]`

Using `None` for filling the gaps and removing them with `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: x is not None, chain(*izip_longest(l1,l2, fillvalue=None)))
```

For better efficiency, when `l1` or `l2` are not short lists but e.g. very long or infinite iterables, instead of `filter` use `ifilter`, which will give you an iterable instead of putting all in memory in a list. Example:

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest, ifilter
for value in ifilter(None, chain(*izip_longest(iter1,iter1))):
    print value
```

Comment: In the first code block, you should only be importing itertools, you don't need the chain, izip_longest functions because you're not using them directly in that block...

Comment: Use a sentinel object() instead of None, but otherwise what I came up with is pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer for different lengths and more lists using zip_longest and filtering out None elements at the end

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']   
c = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']    
[item for sublist in zip_longest(*[a,b,c]) for item in sublist if item]
```

returns

```
[1, 'a', 'A', 2, 'b', 'B', 3, 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: Basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7529841/6243352), but less generalized because it uses `None`. No need for the `*[]` wrapper in the parameter list unless they're already packed; `zip_longest(a, b, c)` works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following (assuming `len(list_long)==len(list_short)+1`:

```
def list_mixing(list_long,list_short):
    return [(list_long[i/2] if i%2==0 else list_short[i/2]) for i in range(len(list_long)+len(list_short)]
```

Where I am using `/` for integer division (exactly what the operator is for that depends on the language version).

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([[x,y] for x,y in zip(b,a)],[])+[b[-1]]
```

Note: This works only for your given list lengths, but can easily be extended to arbitrary length lists.

Comment: Using sum for concatenating is generally discouraged: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: @utdemir: Using `sum` for concatening strings is definitely discouraged -- good thing phimuemue is using it to append to a list.  ;)

Comment: He is concentening lists, from the link i gave: "To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using itertools.chain()."

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily building new lists for every element due to abuse of `sum`. It's quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've found:

```
import itertools

l1 = [1, 3, 5]
l2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

result = [
    x # do something
    for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l1))
    if x is not None
]
result
# [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 8, 10]
```

To make it extra clear, `zip_longest` groups the elements together per index:

```
iter = list(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l1))
iter[0]
# (1, 2, 1)
iter[1]
# (3, 4, 3)
iter[-1] # last
# (None, 10, None)
```

After, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` flattens them in order.

The reasons why it is the best:

- filtering `None` is not recommended anymore, use a list comprehension
- a list comprehension also allows you to immediately "do something" with x
- it does not throw away items when some lists are longer than the shortest one
- it works with any amount of lists
- it is actually super easy to reason what is happening contrary to all the "cleverness" out there

Answer (score -1):

Use zip. That will give you a list of tuples, like:
[('a_1', 'b_1'), ('a_2', 'b_2'), ('a_3', 'b_3')]

If you want to clean that up into a nice list, just iterate over the list of tuples with enumerate:

```
alist = ['a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3']
blist = ['b_1', 'b_2', 'b_3']
clist = []

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    clist.append(a)
    clist.append(b)
print clist
['a_1', 'b_1', 'a_2', 'b_2', 'a_3', 'b_3']
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question.