# Interleave multiple lists of the same length in Python

Tags: python, list

In Python, is there a good way to interleave two lists of the same length?

Say I'm given `[1,2,3]` and `[10,20,30]`. I'd like to transform those into `[1,10,2,20,3,30]`.

Comment: Not recommended, but try this: `it = iter(l1); list((yield next(it)) or i for i in l2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Having posted the question, I've realised that I can simply do the following:

```
[val for pair in zip(l1, l2) for val in pair]
```

where `l1` and `l2` are the two lists.

---

If there are N lists to interleave, then

```
lists = [l1, l2, ...]
[val for tup in zip(*lists) for val in tup]
```

Comment: works only if l1 and l2 have the same number of elements

Comment: @Emmanuel: The question reads "In Python, is there a good way to interleave two lists **of the same length**?"

Comment: If you'd like to pad to longest list, use `izip_longest` for python2 and `zip_longest` for python3
`
`[val for pair in itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2) for val in pair]` results with
`['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', None, 'b', None, 'b', None, 'b']`

Comment: In a for loop, it works like: `for i, j in zip(x,y):`

Comment: `[*zip(l1,l2)]` works nicely in Python 3.8.

Comment: Users of Python 3.10+ can benefit from the `strict` flag on zip to guarantee it will raise on unequal-length lists. https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: [Double for loop / train of for loops in Python list comprehensions explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657720/python-list-comprehension-double-for)

Answer (score 94):

For Python>=2.3, there's [extended slice syntax](http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html):

```
>>> a = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> b = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> c = a + b
>>> c[::2] = a
>>> c[1::2] = b
>>> c
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The line `c = a + b` is used as a simple way to create a new list of exactly the right length (at this stage, its contents are not important). The next two lines do the actual work of interleaving `a` and `b`: the first one assigns the elements of `a` to all the even-numbered indexes of `c`; the second one assigns the elements of `b` to all the odd-numbered indexes of `c`.

Answer (score 43):

**Given**

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 20, 30]
c = [100, 200, 300, 999]
```

**Code**

Assuming lists of equal length, you can get an interleaved list with `itertools.chain` and `zip`:

```
import itertools


list(itertools.chain(*zip(a, b)))
# [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]
```

---

**Alternatives**

*[`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)*

More generally with unequal lists, use `zip_longest` (recommended):

```
[x for x in itertools.chain(*itertools.zip_longest(a, c)) if x is not None]
# [1, 100, 2, 200, 3, 300, 999]
```

Many lists can safely be interleaved:

```
[x for x in itertools.chain(*itertools.zip_longest(a, b, c)) if x is not None]
# [1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200, 3, 30, 300, 999]
```

*[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools)*<sup>+</sup>

A library that ships with the [`roundrobin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) itertools recipe, [`interleave`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.interleave) and [`interleave_longest`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_longest).

```
import more_itertools


list(more_itertools.roundrobin(a, b))
# [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]

list(more_itertools.interleave(a, b))
# [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]

list(more_itertools.interleave_longest(a, c))
# [1, 100, 2, 200, 3, 300, 999]
```

*`yield from`*

Finally, for something interesting in Python 3 (though not recommended):

```
list(filter(None, ((yield from x) for x in zip(a, b))))
# [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]

list([(yield from x) for x in zip(a, b)])
# [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]
```

<sub><sup>+</sup>Install using `pip install more_itertools`</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I needed a way to do this with lists of different sizes which the accepted answer doesn't address.

My solution uses a generator and its usage looks a bit nicer because of it:

```
def interleave(l1, l2):
    iter1 = iter(l1)
    iter2 = iter(l2)
    while True:
        try:
            if iter1 is not None:
                yield next(iter1)
        except StopIteration:
            iter1 = None
        try:
            if iter2 is not None:
                yield next(iter2)
        except StopIteration:
            iter2 = None
        if iter1 is None and iter2 is None:
            raise StopIteration()
```

And its usage:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> list(interleave(a, b))
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> list(interleave(b, a))
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4, 'e', 5, 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: [The `roundrobin` recipe from the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) is a more general extension of this.

Answer (score 7):

Alternative:

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3]
>>> l2=[10,20,30]
>>> [y for x in map(None,l1,l2) for y in x if y is not None]
[1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]
```

This works because [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) works on lists in parallel. It [works the same](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2/lib/built-in-funcs.html) under 2.2. By itself, with `None` as the called functions, `map` produces a list of tuples:

```
>>> map(None,l1,l2,'abcd')
[(1, 10, 'a'), (2, 20, 'b'), (3, 30, 'c'), (None, None, 'd')]
```

Then just flatten the list of tuples.

The advantage, of course, is `map`  will work for any number of lists and will work even if they are different lengths:

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3]
>>> l2=[10,20,30]
>>> l3=[101,102,103,104]
>>> [y for x in map(None,l1,l2,l3) for y in x if y in not None]
[1, 10, 101, 2, 20, 102, 3, 30, 103, 104]
```

Comment: `if y` will filter out `0` too, `if y is not None` is less fragile.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: Thanks! I agree with you. Fixed. I wrote it with only muscles engaged...

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 3):

I like aix's solution best. here is another way I think should work in 2.2:

```
>>> x=range(3)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2]
>>> y=range(7,10)
>>> y
[7, 8, 9]
>>> sum(zip(x,y),[])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
>>> sum(map(list,zip(x,y)),[])
[0, 7, 1, 8, 2, 9]
```

and one more way:

```
>>> a=[x,y]
>>> [a[i][j] for j in range(3) for i in (0,1)]
[0, 7, 1, 8, 2, 9]
```

and:

```
>>> sum((list(i) for i in zip(x,y)),[])
[0, 7, 1, 8, 2, 9]
```

Comment: list(sum(zip(x,y),())) would be nicer, no?

Answer (score 3):

This is also a way to do it:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [10, 20, 30]

list(sum(zip(list1, list2), ()))
```

The idea is similar.

1. zip the lists together. (using zip)
2. flatten to a tuple (using sum(..., ())
3. convert to a list

Answer (score 1):

A funny approach is to use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) with the position in the final list as key:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import count

a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,20,30]

counter = count()
res = list(merge(a, b, key=lambda x: next(counter)))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]
```

For multiple list, you can just unpack them:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import count

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 20, 30]
c = [11, 21, 31]

counter = count()
res = list(merge(*[a, b, c], key=lambda x: next(counter)))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 21, 3, 30, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[el for el in itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest([1,2,3], [4,5])) if el is not None]
```

As long as you don't have `None` that you want to keep

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question's title of "Interleave multiple lists of the same length in Python", we can generalize the 2-list answer of @ekhumoro. This explicitly requires that the lists are the same length, unlike the (elegant) solution by @NPE

```
import itertools

def interleave(lists):
    """Interleave a list of lists.

    :param lists: List of lists; each inner length must be the same length.
    :returns: interleaved single list
    :rtype: list

    """
    if len(set(len(_) for _ in lists)) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Lists are not all the same length!")
    joint = list(itertools.chain(*lists))
    for l_idx, li in enumerate(lists):
        joint[l_idx::len(lists)] = li
    return joint
```

Examples:

```
>>> interleave([[0,2,4], [1, 3, 5]])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> interleave([[0,2,4], [1, 3, 5], [10, 11, 12]])
[0, 1, 10, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 12]
>>> interleave([[0,2,4], [1, 3, 5], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]])
[0, 1, 10, 13, 2, 3, 11, 14, 4, 5, 12, 15]
>>> interleave([[0,2,4], [1, 3, 5], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in interleave
ValueError: Lists are not all the same length!
>>> interleave([[0,2,4]])
[0, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party, and there is plenty of good answers but I would also like to provide a simple solution using `extend()` method:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [10, 20, 30]

new_list = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    new_list.extend([list1[i], list2[i]])
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]
```