# How do I plot a step function with Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

In matplotlib to make a step function you write something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4] 
y = [0.002871972681775004, 0.00514787917410944, 
     0.00863476098280219, 0.012003316194034325]

plt.step(x, y)
plt.show()
```

How do I make a similar graph with Bokeh?

Comment: Bokeh has a built in Step glyph as of `0.12.11`, see Bokeh now has a built-in Step glyph, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507957/3406693 (Other answers here are from before it was added and are out of date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bokeh has a [`Step`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.step) glyph built-in as of version `0.12.11`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("line.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# add a steps renderer
p.step([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=2, mode="center")

show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `line` and some manual work over the arrays. Take in mind an [interleaving of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleaving-two-lists-in-python) for the `y` axis. Also, we want (I guess) to slightly modify the x-values to accomplish right & left limits. Let me offer the following:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import numpy as np
f = figure()
#
# Example vectors (given):
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0.002871972681775004, 0.00514787917410944, 
     0.00863476098280219, 0.012003316194034325]
#
_midVals = np.diff(x)/2.0
xs = set(x[:-1]-_midVals).union(x[1:]+_midVals)
xl = list(xs)
xl.sort()
xx = xl[1:]+xl[:-1]
xx.sort()
yy = y+y
yy[::2] = y
yy[1::2] = y
#
# assert/print coordinates
assert len(xx)==len(yy)
for _p in zip(xx,yy):
    print _p
#
# Plot!
f.line(x=xx, y=yy)
show(f)
```

The exit of our *"sanity check"* print there should be:

```
(0.5, 0.002871972681775004)
(1.5, 0.002871972681775004)
(1.5, 0.00514787917410944)
(2.5, 0.00514787917410944)
(2.5, 0.00863476098280219)
(3.5, 0.00863476098280219)
(3.5, 0.012003316194034325)
(4.5, 0.012003316194034325)
```

And the plot:

[image: example step plot w/ bokeh]

Hope that helps whoever arrives here.

Comment: Bokeh now has a built-in Step glyph, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507957/3406693

Answer (score -1):

I've written a little function that does this using line, a little more in the matplotlib style than @Brandt's answer. In a jupyter notebook, this is

```
def step(fig, xData, yData, color=None, legend=None):
    xx = np.sort(list(xData) + list(xData))
    xx = xx[:-1]
    yy = list(yData) + list(yData)
    yy[::2] = yData
    yy[1::2] = yData
    yy = yy[1:]
    fig.line(xx, yy, color=color, legend=legend)
    return fig
# example
import bokeh.plotting as bok
import bokeh
bokeh.io.output_notebook()

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0.002871972681775004, 0.00514787917410944, 
     0.00863476098280219, 0.012003316194034325]
f = bok.figure()
f = step(f, x, y)
bok.show(f)
```

gives you
[image]

Of course you can replace output_notebook() with whatever output formatting you wish.

Comment: Bokeh now has a built-in Step glyph, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507957/3406693