# Cycle a list from alternating sides

Tags: python, algorithm, list, iteration

Given a list

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

how can I get

```
b = [0,9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5]
```

That is, produce a new list in which each successive element is alternately taken from the two sides of the original list?

Comment: why not deque?! `l1=list(range(10)); d1=deque(l1); [d1.pop() if i%2 else d1.popleft() for i,_ in enumerate(l1) if d1]`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
>>> [a[-i//2] if i % 2 else a[i//2] for i in range(len(a))]
[0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

*Explanation:*
This code picks numbers from the beginning (`a[i//2]`) and from the end (`a[-i//2]`) of `a`, alternatingly (`if i%2 else`). A total of `len(a)` numbers are picked, so this produces no ill effects even if `len(a)` is odd.
`[-i//2 for i in range(len(a))]` yields `0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5`,
`[ i//2 for i in range(len(a))]` yields `0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4`,
and `i%2` alternates between `False` and `True`,
so the indices we extract from `a` are: `0, -1,  1, -2,  2, -3,  3, -4,  4, -5`.

*My assessment of pythonicness:*
The nice thing about this one-liner is that it's short and shows symmetry (`+i//2` and `-i//2`).
**The bad thing, though, is that this symmetry is deceptive:**
One might think that `-i//2` were the same as `i//2` with the sign flipped. [But in Python, integer division returns the floor](http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) of the result instead of truncating towards zero. So `-1//2 == -1`.
Also, I find accessing list elements by index less pythonic than iteration.

Comment: You currently hold the record for only one liner that doesn't need a scroll bar and works with odd length lists, since the OP has [stated they like one liners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533553/how-to-elegantly-cycle-a-list-from-alternating-sides/36533868?noredirect=1#comment60671692_36533951) I'd be inclined to say this is the best answer (+1 btw)

Comment: This is also one of the few answers that doesn't run into issues with odd-sized lists. Well done!

Comment: It fails on the "elegantly" part though, as no one looking at that code can immediately understand what it does.

Comment: @Matsemann at the time of posting this was the cleanest way to do it, Noman [has acknowledged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533553/how-to-elegantly-cycle-a-list-from-alternating-sides/36533624#comment60674430_36533624) that this answer is not immediately obvious and that he prefers my answer for that reason.

Comment: @Matsemann Nah, I wouldn't say no one ;-) But I appreciate what you mean, and I agree. Tadhg's answer is now by far the most pythonic here, in my mind. For the record, I wouldn't mind in the least if OP unaccepted my answer to promote the spirit of true readability.

Answer (score 30):

[`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) between getting items from the forward [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#iter) and the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#reversed) one. Just make sure you stop at `len(a)` with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

iters = cycle((iter(a), reversed(a)))
b = [next(it) for it in islice(iters, len(a))]

>>> b
[0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

This can easily be put into a single line but then it becomes much more difficult to read:

```
[next(it) for it in islice(cycle((iter(a),reversed(a))),len(a))]
```

Putting it in one line would also prevent you from using the other half of the iterators if you wanted to:

```
>>> iters = cycle((iter(a), reversed(a)))
>>> [next(it) for it in islice(iters, len(a))]
[0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
>>> [next(it) for it in islice(iters, len(a))]
[5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Actually, I prefer the two-liner you made from @canaaerus' idea over the accepted answer. Seeing `i//2` I still have to think about why the index needs to be halved, but with `[next(iters[n%2]) for n in a]` I understand *immediately*. IMHO, that two-liner is the truest rendition of "Take numbers alternatingly from front and end of list." I feel it deserves a more prominent position than at the end of your answer.

Comment: @norman I have since edited my post to use `itertools.cycle` which I am even more fond of then my previous version.

Comment: Whoa nice :-) That *is* even better. Are there any limits to the readability of Python code!?

Answer (score 8):

A very nice one-liner in Python 2.7:

```
results = list(sum(zip(a, reversed(a))[:len(a)/2], ()))
>>>> [0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

First you zip the list with its reverse, take *half* that list, sum the tuples to form one tuple, and *then* convert to list.

In Python 3, `zip` returns a generator, so you have have to use `islice` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import islice
results = list(sum(islice(zip(a, reversed(a)),0,int(len(a)/2)),()))
```

*Edit*: It appears this only works perfectly for even-list lengths - odd-list lengths will omit the middle element :( A small correction for `int(len(a)/2)` to `int(len(a)/2) + 1` will give you a duplicate middle value, so be warned.

Comment: TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @canaaerus This works in Python 2.7. Let me see what I can do in Python 3.

Comment: @canaaerus `zip` returns a generator in 3.5, and list in 2.7. Use `itertools.islice`.

Comment: I do like this answer, for python3, according to Akshat: `list(sum(itertools.islice(zip(a, reversed(a)), 0, len(a)//2), ()))`

Comment: this loses the middle value when the list has an odd number of elements.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Dammit. Thanks for pointing that out. I've included that in the answer.

Comment: you could apply the `islice` before `zip`ing and up-/ downrounding respectively.

Comment: @canaaerus Don't quite follow. What would I be applying `islice` to?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: to `a` and to `reversed(a)` respectively.

Comment: @canaaerus That messes with the ordering. I'm getting `(0,5,...)` which is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Just tried `results = list(sum(islice(zip(a, reversed(a)),0,(len(a)+1)//2),()))`, no luck. Still getting a duplicate middle element. Am I getting you correctly?

Comment: Using `sum()` to concatenate an iterable of lists or tuples is a mistake.  It uses quadratic runtime.  Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` or a nested list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you don’t mind sacrificing the source list, `a`, you can just `pop` back and forth:

```
b = [a.pop(-1 if i % 2 else 0) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Edit:

```
b = [a.pop(-bool(i % 2)) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: the original list was `a` and this destroys the original list.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: OP didn't ask for a non-destructive method.

Comment: no but it is something you really want to mention in your answer.

Comment: here is non-destructive alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533553/how-to-elegantly-cycle-a-list-from-alternating-sides#comment60937040_36533553

Answer (score 6):

Use the right [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.org).

```
from toolz import interleave, take

b = list(take(len(a), interleave((a, reversed(a)))))
```

First, I tried something similar to Raymond Hettinger's solution with itertools (Python 3).

```
from itertools import chain, islice

interleaved = chain.from_iterable(zip(a, reversed(a)))
b = list(islice(interleaved, len(a)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Not terribly different from some of the other answers, but it avoids a conditional expression for determining the sign of the index.

```
a = range(10)
b = [a[i // (2*(-1)**(i&1))] for i in a]
```

`i & 1` alternates between 0 and 1. This causes the exponent to alternate between 1 and -1. *This* causes the index divisor to alternate between 2 and -2, which causes the index to alternate from end to end as `i` increases. The sequence is `a[0]`, `a[-1]`, `a[1]`, `a[-2]`, `a[2]`, `a[-3]`, etc.

(I iterate `i` over `a` since in this case each value of `a` is equal to its index. In general, iterate over `range(len(a))`.)

Comment: Damn it, I was just fiddling around with power of -1 myself :-D

Comment: Heh. Feel free to add this to your answer, and I'll delete; it might be slightly more efficient than a branch, but it is decidedly less readable :) As such, it's barely worth an extra answer.

Comment: you might want to use `for i in range(len(a))` for any list other then the direct result of the `range` function.

Answer (score 5):

The basic principle behind your question is a so-called roundrobin algorithm. The [`itertools`-documentation-page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) contains a possible implementation of it:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    """This function is taken from the python documentation!
    roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C
    Recipe credited to George Sakkis"""
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables) # next instead of __next__ for py2
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

so all you have to do is split your list into two sublists one starting from the left end and one from the right end:

```
import math
mid = math.ceil(len(a)/2) # Just so that the next line doesn't need to calculate it twice

list(roundrobin(a[:mid], a[:mid-1:-1]))
# Gives you the desired result: [0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

alternatively you could create a longer list (containing alternating items from sequence going from left to right and the items of the complete sequence going right to left) and only take the relevant elements:

```
list(roundrobin(a, reversed(a)))[:len(a)]
```

or using it as explicit generator with `next`:

```
rr = roundrobin(a, reversed(a))
[next(rr) for _ in range(len(a))]
```

or the **speedy variant** suggested by @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen (thank you!):

```
list(islice(roundrobin(a,reversed(a)),len(a)))
```

Comment: I tend to like this answer, although probably the most efficient use is `b = list(islice(roundrobin(a,reversed(a)),len(a)))` since `reversed` doesn't need to create a whole new list like `[::-1]` does and you might as well use `islice` to cut off the end since again, less list creation overhaul.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I've included the `reversed` in the examples and included your suggestion (I hope properly attributed). Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, whether this can be written more compactly, but it is efficient as it only uses iterators / generators

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

iter1 = iter(a)
iter2 = reversed(a)
b = [item for n, item in enumerate(
        next(iter) for _ in a for iter in (iter1, iter2)
    ) if n < len(a)]
```

Comment: `iters = iter(a), reversed(a) ; b = [next(iters[n%2]) for n in range(len(a))]` originally I posted that in my answer but have since figured out a version I like even more.

Answer (score 4):

Not at all elegant, but it is a clumsy one-liner:

```
a = range(10)
[val for pair in zip(a[:len(a)//2],a[-1:(len(a)//2-1):-1]) for val in pair]
```

**Note that it assumes you are doing this for a list of even length.** If that breaks, then this breaks (it drops the middle term). Note that I got some of the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleaving-two-lists-in-python).

Comment: this loses the middle value when the list has an odd number of elements.

Comment: As noted in my answer. :-) I was actually using this as an excuse to use zip, but you are correct, that usage definitely kills odd length lists.

Answer (score 4):

For fun, here is an itertools variant:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(islice(a, len(a)//2), reversed(a))))
[0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```

This works where `len(a)` is even.  It would need a special code for odd-lengthened input.

Enjoy!

Comment: this loses the middle value when the list has an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 4):

Two versions not seen yet:

```
b = list(sum(zip(a, a[::-1]), ())[:len(a)])
```

and

```
import itertools as it

b = [a[j] for j in it.accumulate(i*(-1)**i for i in range(len(a)))]
```

Comment: Using `accumulate` to get a sequence of indices `[0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5]` is a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = []

for i in mylist:
    result += [i, mylist.pop()]
```

**Note:**

> Beware: Just like @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen has said (see the comment below)
>   it'll destroy half of original list object.

Comment: this destroys half the original list, are you sure you want to be doing that?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You're 100% right! However, we do not know what are the real OP aims.

Comment: this loses the middle value when the list has an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = []
i = 0
j = len(a) - 1
mid = (i + j) / 2
while i <= j:
    if i == mid and len(a) % 2 == 1:
        b.append(a[i])
        break
    b.extend([a[i], a[j]])
    i = i + 1
    j = j - 1

print b
```

Comment: this loses the middle value when the list has an odd number of elements.

Comment: Yes @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen youre right, let me correct it

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this for even-sized lists (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleaving-two-lists-in-python)):

```
a = range(10)

b = [val for pair in zip(a[:5], a[5:][::-1]) for val in pair]
```

Comment: Lol, that's exactly the same as my answer, with the sum and list omitted.

Comment: In fact I wanted to accept your answer (got to love 1-liners) but if I apply it to `a = range(11)`, it loses the number '5'

Comment: @pythonic, long one liners are not very pythonesque so your SO name is very misleading.

Comment: Ha, you have a point. I am unclear which answer should I accept in fact

Comment: @Pythonic A lot of the answers here run into the same issue. Only  Norman's answer solves that and is a short one-liner (other one-liners are longer). I think he won this question and should have accepted answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can partition the list into two parts about the middle, reverse the second half and zip the two partitions, like so:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
mid = len(a)//2
l = []
for x, y in zip(a[:mid], a[:mid-1:-1]):
    l.append(x)
    l.append(y)
# if the length is odd
if len(a) % 2 == 1:
    l.append(a[mid])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
```