# Interleave 4 lists of same length python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want interleave 4 lists of same length in python.

I search this site and only see how to interleave 2 in python: 
[Interleaving two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleaving-two-lists-in-python)

Can give advice for 4 lists?

I have lists like this

```
l1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
l3 = ["w","x","y","z"]
l4 = [5,6,7,8]
```

I want list like

```
l5 = ["a",1,"w",5,"b",2,"x",6,"c",3,"y",7,"d",4,"z",8]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Provided the lists are the same length, [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) can be used to interleave four lists just like it was used for interleaving two in the question you linked:

```
>>> l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l3 = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
>>> l4 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> l5 = [x for y in zip(l1, l2, l3, l4) for x in y]
>>> l5
['a', 1, 'w', 5, 'b', 2, 'x', 6, 'c', 3, 'y', 7, 'd', 4, 'z', 8]
```

Answer (score 26):

[**`itertools.chain`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import chain

l1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l3 = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
l4 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

print(list(chain(*zip(l1, l2, l3, l4))))
```

Or as @PatrickHaugh suggested use [**`chain.from_iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l1, l2, l3, l4)))
```

Comment: I'd probably use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yeah I added to my answer. Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 10):

### From itertools recipes

The [itertool recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) suggest a solution called `roundrobin` that allows for lists of different lengths.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

print(*roundrobin(*lists)) # a 1 w 5 b 2 x 6 c 3 y 7 d 4 z 8
```

### With slicing

Alternatively, here is a solution that relies solely on slicing, but requires that all lists be of equal lengths.

```
l1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
l3 = ["w","x","y","z"]
l4 = [5,6,7,8]

lists = [l1, l2, l3, l4]

lst = [None for _ in range(sum(len(l) for l in lists))]

for i, l in enumerate(lists):
    lst[i:len(lists)*len(l):len(lists)] = l

print(lst) # ['a', 1, 'w', 5, 'b', 2, 'x', 6, 'c', 3, 'y', 7, 'd', 4, 'z', 8]
```

Answer (score 6):

For additional diversity (or for if you need to do this with Pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
l1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
l3 = ["w","x","y","z"]
l4 = [5,6,7,8]

df = pd.DataFrame([l1 ,l2, l3, l4])
result = list(df.values.flatten('A'))
```

> ['a', 1, 'w', 5, 'b', 2, 'x', 6, 'c', 3, 'y', 7, 'd', 4, 'z', 8]

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of diversity, `numpy.dstack` and then `flatten` can do the same trick.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l3 = ["w","x","y","z"]
>>> l4 = [5,6,7,8]
>>> np.dstack((np.array(l1),np.array(l2),np.array(l3),np.array(l4))).flatten()                                                                                                       
array(['a', '1', 'w', '5', 'b', '2', 'x', '6', 'c', '3', 'y', '7', 'd',                                                                                                              
       '4', 'z', '8'],                                                                                                                                                               
      dtype='|S21')
```

BTW you actually don't need to make an array, the short version also works

```
>>> np.dstack((l1,l2,l3,l4)).flatten()                                                                                                       
array(['a', '1', 'w', '5', 'b', '2', 'x', '6', 'c', '3', 'y', '7', 'd',                                                                                                              
       '4', 'z', '8'],                                                                                                                                                               
      dtype='|S21')
```

Answer (score 4):

One other way may be using `zip` with `np.concatenate`:

```
import numpy as np
l5 = np.concatenate(list(zip(l1, l2, l3, l4)))
print(l5)
```

Result:

```
['a' '1' 'w' '5' 'b' '2' 'x' '6' 'c' '3' 'y' '7' 'd' '4' 'z' '8']
```

**Note**: `l5` is type `numpy.ndarray`, you can convert it to `list` either with `list(l5)` or `l5.tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip` and `reduce`:

```
import functools, operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.add, zip(l1,l2,l3,l4))
('a', 1, 'w', 5, 'b', 2, 'x', 6, 'c', 3, 'y', 7, 'd', 4, 'z', 8)
```

Comment: Is there ever a reason to use `functools.reduce(operator.add, x)` instead of `sum(x)`?

Comment: @Daerdemandt No, they're equally bad.

Comment: Yes, because `sum(zip(l1,l2,l3,l4))` does not work: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`