# can i join three list in python (string list and two number list)

Tags: python

is there a way that i can concatenate a string list and 2 number list such that the concatenated list would take them one after the order while joining them.

Input:

```
a = [john, bob, ted, Paul]
b = [22, 34, 56, 12]
c = [13, 98, 78, 60]
```

Expected Ouput:

> ```
> [john, 22, 13, bob, 34, 98, ted, 56, 78, Paul, 12, 60]
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interleaving multiple lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleaving-multiple-lists-in-python)

Comment: if you don't care about the order of the list you can also add the list together like `a + b + c`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `zip` function with list comprehension:

```
a = ['john', 'bob', 'ted', 'Paul']
b = [22, 34, 56, 12]
c = [13, 98, 78, 60]
outcome = [i for t in zip(a, b, c) for i in t]
```

`outcome` would become:

```
['john', 22, 13, 'bob', 34, 98, 'ted', 56, 78, 'Paul', 12, 60]
```

Note that the `c` list in your question has an extra `90` that is not in your expected output, so I removed it believing it's a typo on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Using formatted string and enumerate with list comprehension

```
l = ['{}, {}, {}'.format(a[idx], b[idx], c[idx]) for idx, item in enumerate(a)]
```

> ```
> ['john, 22, 13', 'bob, 34, 98', 'ted, 56, 78', 'Paul, 12, 60']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your lists : 
Make Sure all lists have same dimensions.

```
a = ['john', 'bob', 'ted', 'Paul']
b = [22, 34, 56, 12]
c = [13, 98, 78, 90]
```

Import **numpy** a great module for handling arrays

```
import numpy as np
```

Make numpy array and reshape them as you want

```
a = np.array(a).reshape(-1,1)
b = np.array(b).reshape(-1,1)
c = np.array(c).reshape(-1,1)
```

Concate them along the required axis. In your case it will be 1 (Column wise as we have reshaped the arrays)

```
f= np.concatenate((a,b,c),axis=1)
```

Flatten them in 1D array

```
f = f.flatten()
print(f)
```