# Taking every first, second, third elements from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists that I've created using import random, so their elements and lengths are random.
My aim is to get every first, second, third, etc. from these lists.
For example, these are my two list outputs.

```
My list length is 4
List1 (Original List):   [62, 51, 66, 57]
List 2 (Sum of neighbors of List 1):   [113, 179, 174, 123]
```

My aim is to get,

```
List3: [62, 113, 51, 179, 66, 174, 57, 123]
```

This is my only attempt but it is completely incorrect.

```
def order(list1, list2):
list3=[]
result_num = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    result_num.extend(list1[i::3])
return result_num
result = order(list1)
```

Is it possible to write this program without any third party library? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interleave multiple lists of the same length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleave-multiple-lists-of-the-same-length-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [62, 51, 66, 57]
list2 = [113, 179, 174, 123]

list3 = [value for pair in zip(list1, list2) for value in pair]

print(list3)
# [62, 113, 51, 179, 66, 174, 57, 123]
```

(As a side note, I removed the capital from the names of your lists - the convention in Python is to use capitalized names for classes only)

Comment: I get "'function' object is not iterable" error

Comment: You must have mistyped something. I just checked again, this runs perfectly.

Comment: The fact is as I stated in my question, my numbers are random, so my list1 and list2 were just for example, that's why I get error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can zip two lists up:

```py
def order(list1, list2):
    result_num = []
    for i,j in zip(list1, list2):
        result_num.append(i)
        result_num.append(j)
    return result_num

print(order([62, 51, 66, 57], [113, 179, 174, 123]))
```

Output as requested

**Update:**

Using random for length and contents of lists:

```py
random.seed()
len1 = random.randrange(4,10)
len2 = random.randrange(4,10)
l1 = [random.randrange(1,100) for _ in range(len1)]
l2 = [random.randrange(1,100) for _ in range(len2)]

print(l1)
print(l2)
print(order(l1,l2))
```

Sample output:

```py
[60, 46, 11, 60, 88, 63, 93, 17]
[74, 25, 45, 67, 20]
[60, 74, 46, 25, 11, 45, 60, 67, 88, 20]
```

Comment: I am getting <function order at 0x000001A2A55FBE50> error.

Comment: How can you be getting the same error for all of these different answers? Did you copy my code and run it?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is, as I mentioned in my questiın my lists are random so my given lists are examples, it changes every time. Instead, you used like they are stable.

Comment: Ok, I'll generate some random lists and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed (based on your example) length of your input lists are the same. Something like this should do it:

```py
l1 = [62, 51, 66, 57]
l2 = [113, 179, 174, 123]

list_of_lists = [l1, l2]

l3 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l3 += [l[i] for l in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: Yes, even they are random, lengths are the same, but I get an error from your code

Comment: You're right, "range" was missing, fixed it.

Comment: The error is  "'function' object is not iterable", since I am a beginner can you explain it?