# Creating a sequentially joined list using a for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I need help creating a new list z, where I will have list values as y0, x0, y1, x1, y2, x2, y3 in vertical order as an array.

output: z = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4]

I tried this for loop iteration, but instead of the desired list z, I get only list values as y2, x2.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
x = [[0, 0], [4, 4], [8, 8]]
y = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3 ], [4, 4, 4]

for i in range (0, 3):
    z = [*y[i], *x[i]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleave-multiple-lists-of-the-same-length-in-python

Comment: what happens when you have your last x ? Should the list continue with the remaining y or stop? Please provide the entire solution

Comment: x and y doesn't have the same shape, can you provide the expected output?

Comment: You overwrite `z` in every iteration, why do you expect it to contain the values it did previously? If you meant to _extend_  or _append to_ `z`, then use the `list.extend` or `list.append` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import count

x = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3 ], [4, 4, 4]]
y = [[0, 0], [4, 4], [8, 8]]
counter = count()
z = np.hstack(list(merge(x, y, key=lambda x: next(counter))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution without for loop, first use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) zipped the two lists, chain the results of per loop with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), and then flattened them with `list(chain.from_iterable(iterable_of_list))`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, zip_longest
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(chain.from_iterable, zip_longest(y, x, fillvalue=()))))
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4]
```

Or use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`iconcat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.iconcat) to flatten:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import iconcat
>>> reduce(iconcat, map(chain.from_iterable, zip_longest(y, x, fillvalue=())), [])
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4]
```