# How does this double loop list creation work?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, interleave

The top answer to [Interleave multiple lists of the same length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946798/interleave-multiple-lists-of-the-same-length-in-python) uses a really confusing syntax to interleave two lists `l1` and `l2`:

```
l1 = [1,3,5,7]
l2 = [2,4,6,8]
l3 = [val for pair in zip(l1, l2) for val in pair]
```

and somehow you get `l3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

I understand how list comprehension with a single "`for z in y`" statement works, and I can see that *somehow* we're looping through the zip, and within that through each tuple. But how does that turn a list of four tuples into an interleaved list of eight? Totally bewildered by this line of code.

Comment: If you understand `pair in zip(l1, l2)`, then just read around that, e.g. take each item from every tuple, in order.

Comment: Also, "top answer" depends on your sorting settings. I do not see this solution at the top, but I see others like using `itertools.chain` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954220/2308683

Comment: The `for val in pair` part is just flattening out the tuples that `zip()` gives you.

Answer (score 4):

`zip` returns pair of items from the two list as follows:

```
l_pair = [val for val in zip(l1, l2)]
print(l_pair) # [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

So `zip` will return a list(it actually returns a generator) of tuples, first item from the first list, and second item from the second list.

So for each pair, we add the first item, then the second item of it.

```
l = []
for pair in l_pair:
  for elem in pair:
    l.append(elem)
print(l) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```