# How to elegantly interleave two lists of uneven length?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to merge two lists in Python, with the lists being of different lengths, so that the elements of the shorter list are as equally spaced within the final list as possible.

i.e. I want:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ['a', 'b']

output = [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4]
```

It needs to be able to function with lists that aren't exact multiples too, so it could take:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and produce `[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 5]` or similar.

It needs to preserve the ordering of both lists.

I can see how to do this by a long-winded brute force method but since Python seems to have a vast array of excellent tools to do all sorts of clever things which I don't know about (yet), I wondered whether there's anything more elegant I can use?

---

<sub>If you want regular interleaving (equal-spaced), see [How to interleave two lists of different length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199961/).</sub>

Comment: Why the `'b'` comes between 3 and 4?

Comment: Because it spaces them evenly within the list. I'd take `['a, 1, 2, 'b', 3, 4]` as well but the rotation looks nicer to my eye.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice might help. See also the `itertools` module. Now the important part here is the algorithm, not the tools themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `a` is the longer list and `b` is the shorter

```
from itertools import groupby

len_ab = len(a) + len(b)
groups = groupby(((a[len(a)*i//len_ab], b[len(b)*i//len_ab]) for i in range(len_ab)),
                 key=lambda x:x[0])
[j[i] for k,g in groups for i,j in enumerate(g)]
```

eg

```
>>> a = range(8)
>>> b = list("abc")
>>> len_ab = len(a) + len(b)
>>> groups = groupby(((a[len(a)*i//len_ab], b[len(b)*i//len_ab]) for i in range(len_ab)), key=lambda x:x[0])
>>> [j[i] for k,g in groups for i,j in enumerate(g)]
[0, 'a', 1, 2, 'b', 3, 4, 5, 'c', 6, 7]
```

You can use this trick to make sure `a` is longer than `b`

```
b, a = sorted((a, b), key=len)
```

Comment: This was the solution I went with in the end although I amended the final line to `[j[i] for _,g in groups for i,j in enumerate(g)]` so as to suppress a warning about an unused variable.

Answer (score 12):

Borrowing heavily from Jon Clements' solution, you could write a function that takes an arbitrary number of sequences and returns merged sequence of evenly-spaced items:

```
import itertools as IT

def evenly_spaced(*iterables):
    """
    >>> evenly_spaced(range(10), list('abc'))
    [0, 1, 'a', 2, 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 7, 'c', 8, 9]
    """
    return [item[1] for item in
            sorted(IT.chain.from_iterable(
            zip(IT.count(start=1.0 / (len(seq) + 1), 
                         step=1.0 / (len(seq) + 1)), seq)
            for seq in iterables))]

iterables = [
    ['X']*2,
    range(1, 11),
    ['a']*3
    ]

print(evenly_spaced(*iterables))
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 'a', 3, 'X', 4, 5, 'a', 6, 7, 'X', 8, 'a', 9, 10]
```

Comment: Sorting isn't stable. You can fix it by putting `operator.itemgetter(0)` as the sort key. BTW I posted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59594546/4518341) that includes the fix.

Answer (score 10):

This is basically the same as [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). You can calculate "pixel" positions and use them as the indices into the lists.

Where your task differs is that you only want each element to show up once. You'd need to either modify the algorithm or post-process the indices, appending the elements from the lists only the first time they appear. There is a slight ambiguity, though: when both pixel/list indices change at the same time, you'll need to pick which one to include first. This corresponds to the two different options for interleaving the lists that are mentioned in the question and a comment.

Comment: Indeed it is. What a brilliant piece of lateral thinking.

Answer (score 7):

With the assumption that `a` is the sequence to be inserted into:

```
from itertools import izip, count
from operator import itemgetter
import heapq

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['a', 'b']

fst = enumerate(a)
snd = izip(count(0, len(a) // len(b)), b)
print map(itemgetter(1), heapq.merge(fst, snd))
# [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4]
```

Comment: @JackAidley ugh - of course in Python 3.x you will - one sec ;)

Comment: clever. For python3 it's probably neater to use a list comprehension than `list(map(...))`

Comment: Update  Python 3.5+, the latter will not work.  `heapq.merge()` accepts a [`key` function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge), e.g. `[x for i, x in heapq.merge(fst, snd, key=lambda x: x[0])]`

Answer (score 4):

If we modify @Jon's answer like this

```
from itertools import count
import heapq

[x[1] for x in heapq.merge(izip(count(0, len(b)), a), izip(count(0, len(a)), b))]
```

It doesn't matter which of `a`/`b` is longest

Answer (score 3):

I like [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19293603/4518341) but not the nested style, so I rewrote it. While I was there I noticed the sorting wasn't stable, so I fixed it using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

I also replaced `itertools.count` with `enumerate` because it's more intuitive. As a bonus it should also be more accurate for large inputs, though I haven't tested it.

```
import itertools
import operator

def distribute(sequence):
    """
    Enumerate the sequence evenly over the interval (0, 1).

    >>> list(distribute('abc'))
    [(0.25, 'a'), (0.5, 'b'), (0.75, 'c')]
    """
    m = len(sequence) + 1
    for i, x in enumerate(sequence, 1):
        yield i/m, x

def intersperse(*sequences):
    """
    Evenly intersperse the sequences.

    Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19293603/4518341

    >>> list(intersperse(range(10), 'abc'))
    [0, 1, 'a', 2, 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 7, 'c', 8, 9]
    >>> list(intersperse('XY', range(10), 'abc'))
    [0, 1, 'a', 2, 'X', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'Y', 7, 'c', 8, 9]
    >>> ''.join(intersperse('hlwl', 'eood', 'l r!'))
    'hello world!'
    """
    distributions = map(distribute, sequences)
    get0 = operator.itemgetter(0)
    for _, x in sorted(itertools.chain(*distributions), key=get0):
        yield x
```

Note that there's one difference from your second example, where `'b'` and `'c'` get moved down:

```
>>> list(intersperse(range(1, 6), 'abc'))
[1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4, 'c', 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to do this without itertools:

```
def interleave(l1, l2, default=None):  
    max_l = max(len(l1), len(l2))
    data  = map(lambda x: x + [default] * (max_l - len(x)), [l1,l2])
    return [data[i%2][i/2] for i in xrange(2*max_l)]
```

Ahh, missed the equally spaced part.  This was for some reason marked as duplicate with a question that didn't require equally spaced in the presence of differing list lengths.

Comment: Thanks for answering a question and welcome to SO. For your future reference, your edited comment probably isn't necessary (you could have posted it when you made your edit there) or you could indicated that you edited post, e.g., "**Edit** I missed ..."

Answer (score 1):

A variant of @Jon Clements answer using [`more_itertools.collate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collate) with explanation.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


a, b = range(1, 5), ["a", "b"]
```

**Code**

```
first = enumerate(a)
second = zip(it.count(0, len(a) // len(b)), b)
[x for i, x in mit.collate(first, second, key=lambda x: x[0])]
# [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4]
```

---

**Details**

This answer is updated to use with Python 3.

`first` and `second` are iterables of tuples, each tuple comprising a position-element pair.

```
list(first)
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

list(second)
# [(0, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

`more_itertools.collate()` [wraps `heapq.merge()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#collate), which merges the pre-sorted `first` and `second` iterables in order.  In the final list comprehension, the `key` is the sorting function while the last element in each tuple in returned.

**See Also**

- [`more_itertools.interleave_evenly()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.interleave_evenly) based on the mentioned Bresenham's algorithm.  You will have to determine whether the output is what you want.
- [`heapq.merge()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html) and use it directly.

Install this third-party package via `> pip install more_itertools`

Answer (score 0):

This function will generate an even mixture of any number of lists, without relying on the expensive `sort`

```
from typing import Any, Iterable, List

def evenly_mix(*lists: List[Any]) -> Iterable[Any]:
    m = max(len(b) for b in lists)
    deltas = [len(b) / m for b in lists]
    cnts, psums = [[0 for _ in lists] for _ in [0, 0]]
    for i in range(m):
        for j, b in enumerate(lists):
            psums[j] += deltas[j]
            if psums[j] >= cnts[j] + 1:
                yield b[cnts[j]]
                cnts[j] += 1
```