# Python combine two lists of unequal length in alternating fashion

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, alternation

I have a two lists, and I want to combine them in an alternating fashion, until one runs out, and then I want to keep adding elements from the longer list.

Aka.

```
list1 = [a,b,c]

list2 = [v,w,x,y,z]

result = [a,v,b,w,c,x,y,z]
```

Similar to this question ([Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)), except in these the lists stop combining after the first list has run out :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the simpler version from the excellent [toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.interleave):

```
>>> interleave([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,],[0,0,0]])
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in this [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

For example:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> list1 = list("abc")
>>> list2 = list("uvwxyz")
>>> list(roundrobin(list1, list2))
['a', 'u', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: This only works for Python2.  How would this change for Python3?

Comment: Found the Python3 version of this recipe [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain `map` and list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for t in map(None, a, b) for x in t if x]
['a', 'v', 'b', 'w', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
result = [i for sub in zip(list1, list2) for i in sub]
```

EDIT: Question specifies the longer list should continue at end of shorter list, which this answer does *not* do.

Comment: This has exactly the problem the OP mentions - `zip` truncates the longer list.

Comment: Yes you're right, I misunderstood when he said "these" and thought he was referring to his current problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use zip_longest with [tcathcart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2968103/tcathcart) answer

```
import itertools
result = [i for sub in itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2) for i in sub]
```