# combine lists filling in with blanks python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have three lists

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
l3 = ['z', 'l', 'd', 't', 'm']
```

I want to combine them to create

```
lc = [['a', '1', 'z'], ['b', '2', 'l'], ['c', '3', 'd'],
      [' ', '4', 't'], [' ', ' ', 'm']]
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209754/python-combine-two-lists-of-unequal-length-in-alternating-fashion) shows the [roundrobin iter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#recipes), but it just fills and doesn't do the blanks. I don't understand how to modify the iter to instead of removing the exhausted list but to keep on adding blanks

Comment: `lc = list(itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l3, fill_value=' '))`. Prefix with `i` for Python 2.

Comment: Was trying very hard not to duplicate the question but i just entered in the wrong search terms. This is definitely a duplicate of the others