# Adding 0 for every N numbers - list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm struggling with `list comprehensions`. I need to write a function that will add 0 for every N numbers.
The function looks like this:

```
def makeSpace(list, space):
    list = [list.insert(i, 0) for i in list if ....]
    return list
```

Example, Im passing `makeSpace(list,2)` and if my list looked like: `1,2,3,4,5,6` then after the function should return `1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0`

Can someone tell me how to make it?

PS: If for loop is better for it, it can be traditional `for loop`
I found in a `duplicate` question something and change in on my own:

```
def fun(lst, space):
    i = space
    while i < len(lst):
        lst.insert(i, 0)
        i += space+ 1
    return lst
```

But it does not add number at the end, for example for every 3 space:
`[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6]` it should add also after 6
What should I change?

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: in addition to C.Nivs, you can use `lst`.

Comment: Why must you use a list-comprehension?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Probably because that's what the homework assignment requires.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga will it be easier to use traditional for loop? I've heard it is good to  use `list-comprehansion` .If for loop is easier, then I will add PS in my question.

Comment: @A.Leistra highly doubt such an absurd homework problem would exist. This is not a great use-case for a list comprehension, which should replace functional maps/filters

Comment: @A.Leistra it is not needed, but it would be better for me to understand and get familiar with list-comprehansion

Comment: @must it is good to use list comprehensions when they are useful. It is not good to always use list comprehensions just because you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert element in Python list after every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040525/insert-element-in-python-list-after-every-nth-element)

Comment: modifying the list while looping through it is never a good idea. Try building a new list based on your input and requirements

Comment: @ranjith to be honest, I tried to iterate copied list and add 0 in original list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version with a simple for loop and an independent counter that you increment:

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
idx = 1
new = []
for num in test: 
    new.append(num)
    if idx % 3 == 0:
        new.append(0)

    idx += 1 

print(new)
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Your solution is propably the easiest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something horrendous, like this:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> lst = 1,2,3,4,5,6
>>> [x for i in range(0, len(lst), n) for sub in (lst[i:i+n],(0,)) for x in sub]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0]
```

This is hard to read, and less efficient than a naive implementation using a simple for-loop. Don't use this.

It is *much better* to write clean, well-organized code rather than trying for no reason to write a list-comprehension. If the list-comprehension version doesn't seem obvious, then it almost certainly isn't worth writing. Consider the following solution:

```
>>> def chunk_list_by_n(lst, n):
...     for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
...         yield lst[i:i+n]
...
>>> def foo(lst, n):
...     result = []
...     for chunk in chunk_list_by_n(lst, n):
...         result.extend(chunk)
...         if len(chunk) == n:
...             result.append(0)
...     return result
...
>>> foo((1,2,3,4,5,6),2)
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0]
```

I've used more lines, but I've split up my program into reusable components. When I come back and re-read this a month from now, it will be easier to understand than that horrendous one-liner.