# Insert items from list to another list every n positions

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list.

```python
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
inserted_elements = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I want to get the following by inserting every two elements.

```python
output = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 9, 10, 2]
```

Not only the Python list but also the answer using numpy array is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) based approach, which also works for an arbitrary number of elements to be inserted from one list to the other. For this I've defined a generator function, which will insert and element from `l2` into `l1` every `i` items:

```
def insert_every_n(l1, l2, k):
    i1, i2 = iter(l1), iter(l2)
    while True:
        try:
            yield from islice(i1, k)
            yield next(i2)
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

---

This works by yielding up to `i` items from the iterator `l1` on each iteration by using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). With [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics) we are yielding as many items as there are in the sliced iterable, so the iterable is run to exhaustion, (a shortcut for `for v in g: yield v`).

Finally we can wrap the `yield` statements with a `try`/`expect` to catch the `StopIteration` warning.

---

Let's try with the proposed example:

```
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
inserted_elements = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

list(insert_every_n(vector, inserted_elements, k=2))
# [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 9, 10, 2]
```

And if we wanted to add an item of `l2` every 3 items:

```
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
inserted_elements = [2, 2, 2, 2]

list(insert_every_n(vector, inserted_elements, k=3))
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9, 2, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy NumPy way to do this for any possible size of arrays, but here's a python way of doing so using iterators and list comprehension:

```
it1, it2 = map(iter, (vector, inserted_elements))
n = sum(map(len, (vector, inserted_elements)))

[next(it2) if i % 3 == 0 else next(it1) for i in range(1, n+1)]
# [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 9, 10, 2]
```

Every 3<sup>rd</sup> element in the output will come from `it2`, the iterator for `inserted_elements`. The rest come from `it1` which corresponds to `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

numpy array step:

1.

```
>>> a=np.reshape(np.matrix([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),(5, 2))
>>> a
matrix([[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10]])
```

2.

```
>>> b=np.reshape(np.matrix([2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),(5, 1))
>>> b
matrix([[2],
        [2],
        [2],
        [2],
        [2]])
```

3.

```
>>> M = np.append(a, b, axis=1)
>>> M
matrix([[ 1,  2,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  2],
        [ 5,  6,  2],
        [ 7,  8,  2],
        [ 9, 10,  2]])
```

4.

```
>>> result=np.array(M).flatten()
>>> result
array([ 1,  2,  2,  3,  4,  2,  5,  6,  2,  7,  8,  2,  9, 10,  2])
```

Answer (score 1):

A traditional for-loop approach might look like as follows, where you pick 2 elements from `vector` and 1 element from `inserted_elements` and make the `output` list

```
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
inserted_elements = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

output = []

#Pick two elements from vector and one element from inserted_elements and add it to output list
for idx in range(0,len(vector),2):

    output.extend(vector[idx:idx+2] + [inserted_elements[int(idx/2)]])

print(output)
```

The same thing in list-comprehension will be

```
output = [ v for idx in range(0,len(vector),2) for v in vector[idx:idx+2] + [inserted_elements[int(idx/2)]]]
```

The output will be

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 9, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat obscure approach - but it's faster than anything else (so far):

```
list(itertools.chain(*zip(*[iter(vector)]*2+[iter(inserted_elements)])))
```

It uses a 'idiom' for taking items in size n groups, `[iter(alist)]*n`, and `itertools.chain` as a way of flattening a nested list.

A deleted answer used `np.insert`.  For this I believe `insert` uses masking as demonstrated below:

```
def foo(vector, inserted_elements):
    res = np.zeros(len(vector)+len(inserted_elements),int)  
    mask = res.astype(bool) 
    mask[2::3]=True 
    res[mask]=inserted_elements 
    res[~mask]=vector    
    return res
```

A variation on the `np.append` answer is:

```
np.column_stack((np.reshape(vector,(-1,2)), inserted_elements)).ravel()
```

I generally don't like `np.append`, since it is often misused, especially in loops.  For this it's ok, but I think `column_stack` is cleaner.

===

```
In [254]: list(zip(*[iter(vector)]*2+[iter(inserted_elements)]))                                         
Out[254]: [(1, 2, 2), (3, 4, 2), (5, 6, 2), (7, 8, 2), (9, 10, 2)]
```

Comment: `foo` was what I implemented, only to see that you did it already lol.