# Is there a way to insert elements from a list to every knth position in second list?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to place all the elements from my first list to knth positions of the second list. Where `k = 0,1,2...` and n is a single number. Currently I am doing this (using numpy)

```
#create numpy array
positionList = np.array([])

positions = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

epochs = np.array([10, 11, 12])

for pos,epoch in zip(positions,epochs):
    position = np.insert(pos,0,epoch)

    if len(positionList) > 0:
        positionList = np.concatenate((positionList,position)) 
    else:
        positionList = position

positionList = np.around(positionList,1).tolist()
#expected output [10, 1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 6, 12, 7, 8, 9]
```

Where positions is 2D. I am trying to find the most efficient possible (time and space) way to do this with numpy.

**Note:** The above code does work. I just want to make it efficient.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you provide a better description of what you want to do?

Comment: Do you basically want to zip two arrays as such `a=[a1, a2, a3]; b=[b1, b2, b3]` become `zipped = [a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3]`?

Comment: I hope its clearer now.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040525/insert-element-in-python-list-after-every-nth-element

Comment: I've seen this. But it mentions a single character 'x' to be inserted at kn positions. If I use a loop to iterate through the first array it would still be quadratic time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `axis` parameter of [`np.concatenate()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np


positions = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
epochs = np.array([10, 11, 12])
print(np.concatenate([epochs[..., None], positions], axis=1).ravel())
# [10  1  2  3 11  4  5  6 12  7  8  9]
```

No loops were harmed when writing this code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is actually two `list`s, there is no need to use NumPy here:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [10, 11, 12]

print([z for x, y in zip(b, a) for z in [x] + y])
# [10, 1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 6, 12, 7, 8, 9]
%timeit [z for x, y in zip(b, a) for z in [x] + y]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop
```

or, if `a` is flat and you specify the break every `n` elements:

```
n = 3
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [10, 11, 12]

print([z for x, y in zip(b, zip(*[iter(a)] * n)) for z in (x,) + y])
# [10, 1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 6, 12, 7, 8, 9]
%timeit [z for x, y in zip(b, zip(*[iter(a)] * n)) for z in (x,) + y]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 µs per loop
```

For comparison, here is the NumPy-based solution:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
b = np.array([10, 11, 12])
print(np.concatenate([b[..., None], a], axis=1).ravel().tolist())
# [10, 1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 6, 12, 7, 8, 9]
%timeit np.concatenate([b[..., None], a], axis=1).ravel().tolist()
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.43 µs per loop
```

These indicate that, at least for your inputs, the Python `list`-based solution are actually faster than resorting to NumPy.