# how to add value after every 2 elements in Python List?

Tags: python

I want to add a specific value after every two elements in List.
Ex:

```
zz = ['a','b','c','d','f']
```

i want to add the word: "Hero" and the final look will be :

```
zz = ['a','b','Hero','c','d','Hero','f']
```

i tried to use function insert to put an value in a specific index but it doesnt work this is my code:

```
zz = ['a','b','c','d','f']
count = 0
for x in zz:
    if count == 2:
        zz.insert(count,"Carlos")
    print(x)
    count+=1
```

i think it is far away from the solution im still newbie in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert element in Python list after every nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040525/insert-element-in-python-list-after-every-nth-element)

Comment: Although using `enumerate` and "other complex functions" may not be in your best interest to learn. First figure out with a pen and paper how you do it manually, then implement that into Python instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','f']
n = 2
word = 'Hero'
val_list = [x for y in (letters[i:i+n] + [word] * (i < len(letters) - n) for i in range(0, len(letters), n)) for x in y]

print(val_list)
```

> Here, used nested comprehensions to flatten a list of lists(`[item for subgroup in groups for item in subgroup]`), sliced in groups of `n` with `word` added if less than `n` from end of list.

**Another alternative:**

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','f']
n = 2
word = 'Hero'

for i in range(n, len(letters) + n, n + 1):
    letters.insert(i, word)

print ( letters )
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'Hero', 'c', 'd', 'Hero', 'f']
```

Comment: but your code it seems so hard to understand , is there any reference ?

Comment: Please give an upvote if you like my answer

Comment: Add explanation for you, hope now you will understand