# Is it possible to insert specific sections of one list into a specific location in another list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python, and besides finding it useful and rather easy to understand for the most part, there are still some things I'm unclear of, ergo this question.

**Is it possible to insert specific sections of one list into a specific location in another list?**

Say for example, I have a list called 'a', and in this list I have the numbers 1, 3 and 5 in this format:

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
```

I also have a list called 'b' which contains the numbers 2 and 4 in this format:

```
b = [2, 4]
```

My end goal would be for list 'a' to be changed to this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As you can see, this would require me to specify using indices for both lists to combine them into one list in this custom format, and I am unsure as to how I could go about this.

I unintentionally left out a major detail, and that is the fact that I wanted to make use of the 'insert' function rather than 'append'.

Comment: What exactly is the merging logic? Sorting the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just use `insert()` and have the second argument be a list element.

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
b = [2, 4]
# The first argument is the index to insert it at.
# The second is the actual item to be inserted.
a.insert(1, b[0]) # [1, 2, 3, 5]
a.insert(3, b[1]) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that if you just want `a` sorted, you can just use this:

```
for item in b:
    a.append(item) # Order does not matter, we will sort it later
# a is currently [1, 3, 5, 2, 4] since append() adds to the end of the list
a.sort()
# a is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as sort() re-ordered it
```

Or if you want it even simpler, concatenate them and then sort:

```
a = a + b # [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
a.sort() # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Let me know if this is unclear or not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
a = [1,2,5,6,7]
b = [3,4]
for n,k in enumerate(a):
     if(k<b[0]):
         a = a[0:n]+b+a[n:]
         break
print(a)
```

using the colon to slice arrays is super useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interleaving the lists, you can zip them using [**`izip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 5]
>>> b = [2, 4]

>>> from itertools import izip_longest

>>> [c for pair in izip_longest(a, b)
...  for c in pair if c is not None]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```