# Simplify merging of two numpy arrays at even and uneven points in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I wrote a program that does the job, however it is not very pythonic, not pythonic and definitly not beautiful.

The program  must concatenate two numpy arrays in the following manner:

As an example list0 and list1 are the input

```
list0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list1 = [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]
```

The output should look like the following:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8, 10, 9, 11]
```

So basically put in the number of `list0` at every even point of the output, and put in the number of `list1` at every uneven point.

I am fairly new to python so I wrote it in a C-Style:

```
import numpy as np



list0 = np.arange(10)
list1 = np.arange(2,12)

new = []
cnt0 = 0
cnt1 = 0
for i in range(0,2*len(list0)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        new.append(list0[cnt0])
        cnt0 = cnt0 +1;
    else:
        new.append(list1[cnt1])
        cnt1 = cnt1 +1;
```

Now I want to know if there is a more fancy, pythonic, faster way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion

Comment: Changed it so it is a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being NumPy tagged, here's one with it -

```
np.vstack((list0, list1)).ravel('F').tolist()
```

[`ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) here flattens in `fortran` order with the `F` specifier.

A shorter version with [`np.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) that basically stacks the elements in columns -

```
np.c_[list0,list1].ravel().tolist()
```

`ravel()` here flattens in the default `C` order, so skipped here.

If the final output is to be kept as an array, skip the `.tolist()` from the approaches.

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm. Can you give a hint what the ravel function does ?

Answer (score 1):

Nice one liner with itertools

```
from itertools import chain

chain(*zip(list0, list1))

[0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8, 10, 9, 11]
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of itertools, however I would prefer not to use any additional libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`

```
>>> output = [ data for elem in zip(list0,list1) for data in elem ]
[0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8, 10, 9, 11]
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is great since it does not need any further libs, however I made an edit to the post so it focus now on numpy array. Sry for the mislead.