# How to pair two list in python

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

I think someone may have asked this question already, but for some reasons I just cannot come out good key words to find the answers for it.

I have two separate lists, and I could like to pair them.

```
list_a = [[1,2] [3,4]]
list_b = [[5],[6]]
```

I would like to generate:

```
list_c = [[[1,2],[5]],[[3,4],[6]]]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3678938/6521116)

Comment: Do you want to join them into a new list?

Answer (score 5):

The following code should do the trick!

`list_c = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(list_a, list_b)]`

The `zip` function acts to 'pair' the list elements together, while the list comprehension builds the new list.

Comment: That's a really good one :). Sweet and short, thanks for sharing ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append them to a new list, this is what you want:

```
  list_a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
  list_b = [[5],[6]]
  list_res = []
  for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    list_res.append([a, b])



>list_res
>[[[1, 2], [5]], [[3, 4], [6]]]
```