# Python: Convert two columns of dataframe into one interposed list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert two columns in a dataframe into an interposed list?

ex: I want to do something like

`df`

```
             Open  Close
Date
2016-12-23  1      2
2016-12-27  3      4
2016-12-28  5      6
2016-12-29  0      -1
```

`someFunction(df)`

`>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, -1]`

Closest I've found is `list(zip(df.Open, df.Close)` but that returns a bunch of tuples in the list like this: `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (0, -1)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.values.flatten()                                                                                                                                                                  
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0, -1])
```

Comment: Ah, what if there are a bunch of other columns in between? Is there a more pythonic way than just grabbing the first 2 columns into its own DF or dropping the rest of the columns?

Comment: If you want, you can just pick the columns you want to flatten:  df[['Open', 'Close']].values.flatten()

Comment: this is: `df.stack().values`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.values.ravel().tolist()#df.to_numpy().ravel().tolist()

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, -1]
```

Comment: may I know the reason downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
df.stack().values
#array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0, -1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the values, and reshape it to a 1d array:

```
>>> df[['Open', 'Close']].values.reshape(-1)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  0, -1])
```

or convert that to a list:

```
>>> list(df[['Open', 'Close']].values.reshape(-1))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension in combination with `df.values`:

```
[y for x in df.values for y in x]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, -1]
```

`x` will be an array with the rows, and `y` will be the values in those rows