# Best way to concatenate a list of digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy-ndarray

**Example 1**

```
list1 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
list2 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

concated_list1_and_list2  = [[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1]]
```

**Example 2**

```
list1 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
list2 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

concated_list1_and_list2  = [[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0]]
```

**Example 3**

```
list1 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
list2 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

concated_list1_and_list2  = [[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1]]
```

I want to concatenate two lists in a decent manner states that without using loops such as concatenating along the axis or reshaping and again concatinating

Comment: item 1 concatenates differently than items 0 and 2? More info please (Also, I would this call merge, not concatenate, concatenate would be more like `[1,1,1,0,0,0]`)

Comment: your example is weird and does not follow a specific pattern

Comment: Check out the updated example

Comment: Just do it in a non-decent manner (for whatever you deem decent) and see whether it's fast enough for your purposes. If you can't get it to work, or it really needs to be faster, you'll have a better question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What constitutes a decent manner is a matter of opinion. Please be accurate.

Comment: In the first example, why is the second list `[0,1,0,1,0,1]`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: refer to this similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has the same output than the examples:

```
def merge(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for index, (item1, item2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        item = []
        for subitem1, subitem2 in zip(item1, item2):
            if index % 2 == 0:
                item.append(subitem1)
                item.append(subitem2)
            else:
                item.append(subitem2)
                item.append(subitem1)
        result.append(item)
    return result
```

or with list comprehension, imho less readable (based on Ch3steR's answer):

```
[[j for t in zip(*i) for j in t] if idx % 2 == 0 else [j for t in zip(*i) for j in reversed(t)] for idx, i in enumerate(zip(list1,list2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should say you want the element's order be determined by position in original list. 
A simple comprehension won't do it now, we need something that tracks the index

```
final_result = []
for index, (item1, item2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    temp = []
    current_lists = zip(item1, item2) if index%2==0 else zip(item2, item1)
    [temp.append(element1), temp.append(element2) for element1, element2 in current_lists] 
    final_result.append(temp)
```

Answer (score -1):

The order will not be as you showed in examples, but it may seem as the simplest way.

```py
list(a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```