# Combining of two lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with elements and an empty list:

```py
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [7,8,9]
l3 = []
```

How can I add the elements of `l1` and `l2` into `l3`, like that:

```sh
l3 = [1,7,2,8,3,9,4,5,6]
```

Comment: It seems you want to add elements into the resulted list **alternately** from the first and the second list. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion) about ways for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [7,8,9]
l3 = []


for i in range(len(l1)):     #iterates through indices of l1
    l3.append(l1[i])         #adds elements of l1 to l3 for index currently in loop for
    if l2:                   #if l2 is still not empty...
        l3.append(l2.pop(0)) #removes first element from l2 and adds it to l3 

print(l3)                    #outputs [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: By the way what can we do if i don't want to erase l2 elements?

Comment: Maybe something like this could be shorter:
`l = l1 + l2 + l3; l = l[0::3] + l[1::3] + l[2::3]`