# how do you merge two lists in python

Tags: python

```
Studentnames = [a, b, c]
StudentMarks = [10, 20, 30]
```

expected output:

```
Student_names_marks = [a, 10, b, 20, c, 30]
```

Comment: Variable names are not allowed to have spaces. further more, I think this solves your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do something like this-

```py
output = list()
for x, y in zip(Studentnames, StudentMarks):
  output.extend([x, y])
```

The list `output` would then have the concatenated version