# Understanding python list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I was seeking a solution for [Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion) And I came across this elegant solution by @Someone.

```
[x for y in zip(list1, list2) for x in y]
```

It works like a charm, but I do not understand how the variables `x` and `y` are being assigned here. What is really going on in the list comprehension?

Comment: The linked duplicate explains how the variables work in list comprehensions, they work the same as for-loops, essentially

Comment: Note, this is pretty much the equivalent of `from itertools import chain` then `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))`

Comment: I don't quite agree that this is a duplicate question. The double iteration of the variables makes things a little more complex than the standard one liner if else statement. Nonetheless, I understand now from the link, thanks for that! Never knew that list comprehension could be so powerful