# how to merge 2 lists (list1 = ["a", "c"] and list2 = ["b", "d"]) one by one so at the end it looks like (finalList = ["a", "b" , "c", "d"])

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.8

i am trying to combine list1 and list2 in a way that in the end list would look like this ["a", "b" , "c", "d"]

How do i do this?

```
list1 = ["a", "c"]
list2 = ["b", "d"]
```

Comment: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))`

Comment: For **fun** `sum(zip(list1, list2), ( ))`. ' : ). You can convert that to `list` if it matters

Comment: or `[v for pair in zip(list1, list2) for v in pair]`. Hrm, feels like there are many ways. I would consider the first one, or this one for real use. **Also, feels like a duplicate**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to combine two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)

Comment: Did you want it sorted or did you intend to get the first index of each, then the second index of each?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sorted() function python provides in the following way:

```
    list1 = ["a", "c"]
    list2 = ["b", "d"]
    res = sorted(list1 + list2)
```

The `+` operator will first append the 2 lists together, the result of which is `['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']`. It is then passed to the `sorted()` python function, which will sort the contents of the list in the ascending order as desired i.e. `['a','b','c','d']`

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["a", "c"]
list2 = ["b", "d"]

list3 = list1 + list2
list3.sort()

print(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways, but the main idea is to use `zip` to merge them,

```
>>> list1
['a', 'c']
>>> list2
['b', 'd']
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2))
... )
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> sum(zip(list1, list2), ()) # just for fun
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> [v for pair in zip(list1, list2) for v in pair]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, zip(list1, list2), ()) # is kinda bad, because it's a bit hard to reason about but fun
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> list(itertools.chain(*zip(list1, list2)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Cool. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `extend()` and `sort()` functions;

```
list1.extend(list2)
list1.sort()
print(list1)
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Budy you can do this by simply add list1 and list2 and assign result to finallist and then sort final list.
Then  you can get desired result.

```
list1=["a","c"]
list2=["b","d"]
finallist=list1+list2
finallist.sort()
print(finallist)
```

Output:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```