# How to order a list in this fashion: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have list_A and list_B:
list_A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list_B = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

How can achieve a third list mixing them like this: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

Language: Python 3

Thanks

Comment: Does it answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks! I was deep under this trying to solve it and finding no answers on internet.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
list_A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list_B = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
c = list(zip(list_A,list_B))
print (c)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Or are you looking for :

```
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: The second one is what i'm looking for. Aniket provided me an answer to my question :)